# Explicit assignment pattern type

Tags: system-verilog

I'd like to be able to provide an explicit struct type in an assignment pattern (1800-2012 sec. 10.9) so that the left-hand side of the assignment does not need to be of that struct type. Is there a way to accomplish this?

For example, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
typedef struct packed { logic s1; logic s2 } struct_t;
logic a, b;
logic [1:0] c;

assign c = struct_t'{s1:a, s2:b};
```

An alternative would be to do:

```
typedef struct packed { logic s1; logic s2 } struct_t;
logic a, b;
struct_t tmp;
logic [1:0] c;

always_comb begin
    tmp = '{s1:a, s2:b};
    c   = tmp;
end
```

But that has the obvious disadvantage of requiring a temporary variable.

I didn't see any mention of something like this in the standard. Additionally, I tried it with QuestaSim and it didn't work, though it also didn't complain about a syntax error with the expression `struct_t'{s1:a, s2:b};`. Based on the syntax table for assignment patterns, this appears to be invalid syntax. Is that right?

Is there some way to achieve what I want? I also tried to cast the assignment pattern, like `struct_t'('{s1:a, s2:b})`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these are all packed types, they should all be assignment compatible.

I get a syntax error in your typedef - missing a semicolon after `s2`

```
** Error: (vlog-13069) myfile.sv(3): near "}": syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';' or ','.
```

Once I fix that, it works for me. If you don't agree please show a complete example with the actual errors.

Comment: Yes, you're right this works fine. My issue was elsewhere, which became clear when creating the full MWE. Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: It's still not entirely clear to me why `struct_t'{...}` is valid syntax according to the standards doc. As far as I can tell, the standard simply specifies `'{...}`. If you can reference the part of the standard where this is specified as valid, that would be very much appreciated. I used it simply as a sort of guess based on the fact that `type'(...)` is used elsewhere as a type cast.

Comment: It's buried in section 10.9  `assignment_pattern_expression ::= [ assignment_pattern_expression_type ] assignment_pattern` And there is an example right after that `shortint'({T'{1,2}, T'{3,4}}) // yields 16'sh1234`